# Does anyone knows why mat-sort won't work in this piece?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I am using Angular to render a mat-table and mat-sort won't work. This is my code in HTML (ng-template used to render cells, but I quite sure that doesn't affect mat-sort):

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
    <ng-container
      [matColumnDef]="column"
      *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns"
    >
      <th
        mat-header-cell
        mat-sort-header
        *matHeaderCellDef
      >
        <span>
          {{ column }}
        </span>
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <ng-container
          *ngTemplateOutlet="
            renderCell;
            context: { element: element, column: column }
          "
        ></ng-container>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
  </table>
```

And this is my .ts:

```
 @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false })
  public sort: MatSort;

  constructor(
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you share your full code. Want see how the data source defined

Comment: Datasource is passed from parent to this component, and it's done like this:

```@Input("data")
  set data(data: any) {
    this._data = data;
    if (data.length) {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
      this.displayedColumns = Object.keys(this.data[0]);
    }
  }

  get data() {
    return this._data;
  }```